# With GCP Compute Engine, how do I create a custom role, enabling only these three activities: start, stop, ssh, and nothing more?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-iam

1. Summarize the problem

I want to grant to a user, the ability to perform these three activities only on GCE.

1. start a specific instance (from the console, or any other method)
2. stop that same specific instance
3. ssh (direct ssh command, or gcloud ssh)

and nothing more.  Simply and only 1. & 2. would work also, as no GCE permissions need be granted to allow ssh (can be done through ssh).

The user will not have any permissions to edit the instance in any way, would not be able to delete the instance, would not be able to add or delete disks, or change any aspect of networking, nor would the user be able to start/stop or ssh into the other GCE VM's in the same project.

I wish to create a role, that would be tied to a specific existing VM, and grant those three permissions (or a combination of permissions, that would allow those three activities) to a specific user with a GCP account.

---

2. Provide background including what you've already tried.

I have read thoroughly through all the IAM / roles documentation for GCE.  I see no way to apply these fine grained permissions to a specific, existing VM.

Reference:
`https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/iam`

This is the document I am reading, searching for answers.  I see nothing here that would allow this.

I am hoping that I am missing something, that there is some magic or incantation that would allow this.

4. Describe expected and actual results including any error messages

From the documentation I have read, any permissions that can be granted, are too far reaching.  It is seemingly give everything (ability to edit the instance including creating, modifying other VM instances), or nothing at all.

Answer (score 2):

Updated answer based on the comments:

You would need to create a custom role and attach the specific permissions. Below is the sample terraform code to do that. The sample below creates a custom role which allows only authenticating with the GKE cluster, nothing else.

```
# Deleted custom roles prevent similarly named roles from being created for up to 30 days
resource "random_string" "role_suffix" {
  length  = 8
  special = false
}

# Allow frontend/test user to only authenticate
resource "google_project_iam_custom_role" "kube-api-ro" {
  project = local.project_id
  role_id = "kube_api_ro_${random_string.role_suffix.result}"

  title       = "Kubernetes API (RO)"
  description = "Grants read-only API access that can be further restricted with RBAC"

  permissions = [
    "container.apiServices.get",
    "container.apiServices.list",
    "container.clusters.get",
    "container.clusters.getCredentials",
  ]
}

resource "google_project_iam_binding" "kube-api-ro" {
  project = local.project_id
  role    = "projects/${local.project_id}/roles/${google_project_iam_custom_role.kube-api-ro.role_id}"

  members = [
    "user:${var.rbac_test_user}",
  ]
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your response, this provides valuable information.

Here is a link to *Compute Instance Admin Role* that I would be granting.
`https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/iam#compute.instanceAdmin`

The permissions I would be granting, provide much more than just simply starting/stopping a specific instance.

Comment: The requirements I have are to grant no more privileges than absolutely needed.

The only activities that I wish to grant are start/stop, nothing more.

If there are any additional permissions granted beyond this, by granting the 'compute.instanceAdmin' role, then I would need to find another way to solve this problem.

The 'compute.instanceAdmin' role grants 57 additional permissions beyond start/stop, which does not meet the requirements in the issue/problem I posted.